# Al guardar usuario como saber si se inserto o ya habia un usuario con ese email/nombreUsuario

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

sigo aqui con `PHP`.

Estoy **insertando** un usuario a mi **BD**.

Mi **BD**:

```
`usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usuario` (`usuario`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Mi **form.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario BD</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="operaciones.php">

        <label>nombre</label> <input type="text" name="nombre"> <br>
        <label>apellidos</label> <input type="text" name="apellidos"> <br>
        <label>usuario</label> <input type="text" name="usuario"> <br>
        <label>email</label> <input type="email" name="email"> <br>
        <label>password</label> <input type="password" name="password"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="registrarse">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi **operaciones.php**:

```
<?php 
    include('conexion.php');

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    //ATENCION =  en este caso las variables deben de llevar comillas en el 'VALUES'
     $solicitud = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,apellidos,usuario,email,password) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellidos','$usuario','$email','$password')";


     $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $solicitud);


 ?>
```

Mi **conexion.php**:

```
<?php 

$host = "secreto";
$user = "secreto";
$password = "secreto";
$db = "secreto";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

//asi sabe que cuando emplee la conexion debe usarse con el 'charset' UTF-8
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");




 ?>
```

Pues cuando **envio el formulario**  me **guarda** el usuario, pero si **existe** el **usuario** o el **email** no me sale ningun `error`, simplemene me lleva tambien a la **pagina en blanco** (que es el fichero `operaciones.php`)

Comment: pero te lo guarda en la base de datos?? Pk lo normal es ke pongas ambos casos como campos unique, captures el error de la consulta y lo manejes en php para pasarlo a tu html

Comment: si el usuario o email ya esta insertado **no me inserta nada** , como podria manejar el error y mostrarlo en la vista ?

Comment: Puedes comprobarlo manualmente antes de insertar, buscando si el usuario y/o el email ya existen en la base de datos. Así, de paso, puedes devolverle al usuario un mensaje tipo "¿Ha olvidado la contraseña?" Si ya existe en BBDD